# Mongodb $merge : what is the relevence of document size in $merge aggregation query?

Tags: mongodb, merge

I am merging one collection documents into another collection using mongodb merge aggregation. I am trying to merge 10 fields of basic details i.e. name, age, dob etc. into another collection using a unique key. My mongodb query is given below :

```
db.collection1.aggregate([
    {
    $project:
        {
        _id:0, 
        <fieldsList>:1
        }
    },
    {
        $merge : { into: "collection2", on: "<unique_field>",  whenMatched: "keepExisting", whenNotMatched: "insert" 
     }
    }
])
```

The query gives me an error given below :

The full response is:

```
{ 
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1677514685, 51), 
    "ok" : 0.0, 
    "errmsg" : "BSONObj size: 20141031 (0x13353E7) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB) First element: update: \"collection2\"", 
    "code" : NumberInt(10334), 
    "codeName" : "BSONObjectTooLarge", 
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1677514685, 51), 
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0, "7xcBrDcNZ+/bCEJ2gSFuIojEkjI="), 
            "keyId" : NumberLong(7174701554677579780)
        }
    }
}
```

Total documents to be merged around 6 million.

This makes me wonder that why am i getting document size error when no single document that will be merged is more than even 512 kb. Let me know if i am understanding the merge query wrong.

I expect that the query should work fine because no single document is more than 16 MB.

Comment: Term "lakh" is rather unknown outside if India

Comment: `no single document is more than 16 MB.` - mostlikely it's not true and there is at least one resulted document bigger than 16 MB, try applying this pipeline on limited scope of records and if it works, expand the affected records step by step

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit sorry for that, its actually 60 lakhs = 6 millions.

Comment: @dododo its not possible because in that case mongodb will not allow this document to be stored in <collection 1> itself.

Comment: Is your `<unique_field>` really unique? Maybe provide some more real code and sample data.

Comment: Yes it is unique, in both the collections @WernfriedDomscheit

Comment: finally found the bug, its because of the mongodb version 4.4.17 as its mentioned in the release notes

4.4.18 - Nov 21, 2022
Issues fixed:

SERVER-66289
 $out incorrectly throws BSONObj size error on v5.0.8

the bug is resolved in the version 4.4.18, anyways thanks for the support @WernfriedDomscheit